# Static method recursion, by wrapping root-methods

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a way to have a class with top-level static methods, (eg. `mkdir`, `readFile`), then add a `static get` prefix, that is a anonymous class that inherits the parent. What I'd like in this example, is for `FileSystem.stat` and a `FileSystem.suppress.stat` one that behaves async, and one won't throw if there's no file existing.

```
function asyncSupress (fn) { 
  return async (...args) => { 
    try { 
      const res = await fn(...args)
      return res
    } catch (e) { 
      return null
    }
  }
}

export class FileSystem {
  static wrap: any = promisify
  static mkdir = FileSystem.wrap(nodeFs.mkdir)
  static writeFile = FileSystem.wrap(nodeFs.writeFile)
  static readFile = FileSystem.wrap(nodeFs.readFile)
  static stat = FileSystem.wrap(nodeFs.stat)
  static readdir = FileSystem.wrap(nodeFs.readdir)

  static get suppress() { 
    return class extends FileSystem { 
      static wrap = (fn) => asyncSupress(promisify(fn))
    }
  }

}
```

This isn't working as I'd like because `FileSystem.wrap` isn't `this.wrap`.

Is there any way to get this to work as I'd expect?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a better way of doing it:

```
export class FileSystem {
  static mkdir = promisify(nodeFs.mkdir)
  static writeFile = promisify(nodeFs.writeFile)
  static readFile = promisify(nodeFs.readFile)
  static stat = promisify(nodeFs.stat)
  static readdir = promisify(nodeFs.readdir)
  static get suppress() { 
    return class { 
      static stat = asyncSupress(FileSystem.stat)
    }
  }
}
```